# Сохранение двух обьектов в одном запроса Django Rest Framework

Tags: django-rest-framework

Решил попробовать сохранить два обьекта в одном запросе, переопределив сериализатор djoser для создания юзера(хочу авторизовываться по его юрлке):

```
{
"email": "wht118@mail.ru",
"password": "12345",
"user_customer": {
        "name": "bbbbb",
        "surname": "aaaaa",
        "phone": "+71234567",
        "address": "ул.Пушкина"
    }
}
```

По сути попытался симитировать создание юзера и одновременное создание контактной информации о нем. Однако, джанго не позволяет мне сериализовать user_customer как обьект.
Сам код сериализаторов выглядит следующим образом:

```
User = get_user_model()

class CustomerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        exclude = ['id']



class RegisterUserSerializer(UserCreateSerializer):
    user_customer = CustomerSerializer(many=False, read_only=False)

    class Meta(UserCreateSerializer.Meta):
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user_customer = validated_data.pop('user_customer')
        user = User.objects.create(**validated_data)
        Customer.objects.create(id=user, **user_customer)
        return user

#так как метод save лишь вызывает perform_create и обрабатывает исключение, переопределим его
    def perform_create(self, validated_data, *args, **kwargs):
        with transaction.atomic():
            user_customer = validated_data.pop('user_customer')
            email = validated_data.pop('email')
            password = validated_data.pop('password')
            user = User.objects.create_user(email=email, password=password)
            Customer.objects.create(id=user, **user_customer)
            return user
```

При таких данных и таком состоянии кода вылетает ошибка, что QueryDict с данными user_customer не может быть инстансом Customer(что довольно логично). Не могу понять, как и что мне лучше сделать, чтобы это заработало? Впринципе есть несколько вариантов: либо самому написать метод во вьюшке, что впринципе не сложно, но очень хочется, чтобы все было красиво, лаконично и автоматически(кейс то вроде довольно дефолтный); либо переписать to_representation у CustomerSerializer, что, откровенно говоря, красивым и лаконичным не назовешь.
Очень бы хотел услышать ваши идеи по данному вопросу и найти решение данного кейса на будущее.

Answer (score 0):

Вообщем, вся проблема в том, что в Djoser в своем сериализаторе UserCreateSerializer(от которого наследуется мой сериализатор), вызывает метод validate с данными, в которых находится мой user_customer. Недолго подумав, решил проблему переопределив метод validate таким образом:

```
    def validate(self, attrs):
        attrs_without_customer = attrs.copy()
        attrs_without_customer.pop('user_customer')
        super().validate(attrs_without_customer)
        return attrs
```